# Retrieve and change the point at which touchUpInside changes to touchUpOutside

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton, uislider

I have made a `UISlider` work just like the "slide to unlock" slider.
What I need to do is determine the point at which lifting your finger off is classed as `touchUpOUTSIDE` and not `touchUpINSIDE`. This is the point where you slide your finger past the end of the slider too far.
I guess it's the same as with a `UIButton`, you can press the button then slide your finger off the button and depending how far you go, it can still be classed as `touchUpInside`.
If possible, i'd like to mark the target area with a circle.

Once i've managed to find where this point is, is it possible to change it? So I could have a bigger target area?

I really don't know where to start with this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's taken me a few hours, but i've managed to sort this.
I've done a lot of testing overriding touchesMoved, touchesEnded and sendAction:action:target:event and it seems that any touch within 70px of the frame classes as a touch INSIDE. So for a UISlider that's 292x52 any touch from x:-70 to x:362 or y:-70 to 122 will count as an inside touch, even though it's outside the frame.

I have come up with this code that will override a custom class to allow a bigger area of 100px around the frame to count as an inside touch:

```
#import "UICustomSlider.h"

@implementation UICustomSlider {
    BOOL callTouchInside;
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    callTouchInside = NO;
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint touchLocation = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    if (touchLocation.x > -100 && touchLocation.x < self.bounds.size.width +100 && touchLocation.y > -100 && touchLocation.y < self.bounds.size.height +100) callTouchInside = YES;

    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}

-(void)sendAction:(SEL)action to:(id)target forEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (action == @selector(sliderTouchOutside)) {                          // This is the selector used for UIControlEventTouchUpOutside
        if (callTouchInside == YES) {
            NSLog(@"Overriding an outside touch to be an inside touch");
            [self sendAction:@selector(UnLockIt) to:target forEvent:event]; // This is the selector used for UIControlEventTouchUpInside
        } else {
            [super sendAction:action to:target forEvent:event];
        }
    } else {
        [super sendAction:action to:target forEvent:event];
    }
}
```

With a little bit more tweaking I should be able to use it for the opposite also. (Using a closer touch as an outside touch).

Comment: This seems like a lot of extra work. Why exactly do you need the touch to be an inside touch when it's really an out?

Comment: Because its easy to swipe your finger past the end of the scroller and it bounces back. This way if you swipe past the end it still classes as an unluck.

Comment: Oh and where I say outside touch above, I actually mean a touch that's started inside but moved outside.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, the `UIControlEventTouchUpOutside` event is triggered when the finger is outside the bounds of the control. If you're trying to change that area, the slider will scale with it. Why not just tie the action for `UIControlEventTouchUpOutside` to the same as `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`?

Comment: It seems to have a bigger area than the bounds. If you press a UIButton and slide your finger off the button it stays highlighted for a certain distance away from the button. This still classes as inside but is outside the bounds of the button.

Comment: The system does a lot of guessing where your finger is actually at. All we can really rely on is Apples documentation. If you want to try and test out the location for yourself, just track the location of the touch and record the coordinates when the event changes.

Comment: This question also says about the touch bounds being bigger http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300528/strange-uibutton-behavior-is-that-normal