# How to increase the UIButton hittest area?

Tags: ios, uibutton, hittest

i need some help for a rapid prototype iPad app demo.

I have a large background image with some graphical elements.
Then i created a custom UIButton onto this view.
Unfortunately i need to increase the hit test area of that button.with,
so the user should think that touching on that graphical background element also has the same functionality than pressing the button which is placed directly next to that detail.

By overriding the hittest:withEvent method, the button will be highlighted but unfortunately its target/selector are not invoked for UIControlEventTouchUpInside.

Any idea how to make it work?
Thanks for any help

**Update:**
Within the UIControl Class reference, i found the "sendActionsForControlEvents" method which i included like this directly before the "return self":

```
    [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Now the touch will be recognized but then the "Hittest" log will be called twice.
I just need to call it twice. If there´s an way to do it, i will be fine :)

**Update 2:**

Here´s a sample chart, hope that helps.

```
@implementation HotSpotButton
@synthesize data = _data;  
- (id)initWithDictionary:(HotSpotDataObject*)hotspotData
{        
    self.data = hotspotData;

    UIImage* img = loadImageWithoutCaching(@"infospot.png");     
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(hotspotData.posX, hotspotData.posY, img.size.width, img.size.height);

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];  //clearColor
        [self setAlpha:1];
        [self setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self setAdjustsImageWhenHighlighted:YES];
        [self setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];    

        // Animate the hotspot itself ==================================
         CABasicAnimation *scale =[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"]; 
        // some pusling 
        [self.layer addAnimation:scale forKey:@"animateScale"];  
    }
    return self;
}

- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    int errorMargin = 30;
    CGRect largerFrame = CGRectMake(0 - errorMargin, 0 - errorMargin, self.frame.size.width + errorMargin + 1024, self.frame.size.height + errorMargin);

    if ((CGRectContainsPoint(largerFrame, point)) == 1){
        NSLog(@"HITTEST");

        [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];        
        return self;
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Outside");
        return nil;
    }

}
@end
```

Comment: What are your log statements showing?

Comment: When i press my button within 400px to the right, the "HITTEST" will be called once, so it seems it works. But the UIControlEventTouchUpInside won´t be called ;(

Comment: Is it called when you hit on the actual button?

Comment: Yeah it is called when i press the button within the graphical area. And three HITTest logs are printed.

Answer (score 2):

It is a lot easier!!!

You can make the frame of the `UIButton` a lot bigger than the button image actually is and then align the image of the button where you want it to be:

```
[someButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -9, self.view.frame.size.width+9, self.view.frame.size.height)];
//set image instead of this comment
someButton.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentTop;
someButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentRight;
```

...for instance.

If you want your image somewhere really specific, you can subclass a UIControl and add the image you want, where you want it to be, as a subview. Easy.

Now, I think, you don't need the hitTest method anymore...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately that doesn´t work. There is no increase of the target size. Also because of the change of the frame, it can´t use it. Because depending on the pressed button, i need to display further stuff at the button.frame.origin.x. Therefore the additional content would be displayed outside of the screen ;( Therefore i think the "sendActionsForControlEvents" will be a solution, but it still doesn´t work correctly :( Thanks for your help

Comment: Then I don't really know, what you want. If you did post a screenshot, we all could get closer and help you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly. I believe you want to increase/decrease the touchUpInside area. The point at which it changes from Inside to Outside?

I did this with the thumb area of a UISlider. Have a look at my question and answer here [Retrieve and change the point at which touchUpInside changes to touchUpOutside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899552/retrieve-and-change-the-point-at-which-touchupinside-changes-to-touchupoutside)
It's achieved by overriding the touch methods of the UIButton, so you'll have to subclass UIButton.

If you plot the coordinates in the touchesEnded method, you'll see it creates a bigger box around the button, so you simply need to change the coordinates to fit your needs.

Comment: Actually. I don't think this will do what you want. This increases the area once you press the button and drag your finger off it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your code is called twice, because I believe the 'self' in this code is referring to the View?

```
[self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

You should use:

```
[self.myButton sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; This line is written directly within my custom button "hitTest:withEvent" method, self.myButton isn´t available there. But thanks...